# Can't change opacity of scene strip in Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In the VSE, I have a scene strip, but I cannot change the opacity.  It just snaps back to the last value it was keyframed at as soon as I alter it.

(Blender 2.69)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is already a [known issue](https://developer.blender.org/T32890) that is on the To Do list for the VSE.  I'm posting this Q&A because it took me a long time to come across the solution.

As explained in the above bug report, in order to keyframe a scene clip, you must turn off the preview.

[image]

Comment: It's so tedious those little things. VSE is probably the most unfinished part of blender.