# Opacity animation disappears in render

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor

I'm using opacity animation to make an animated text fade out. It's working in the Video Sequence Editor, but when I render the video it doesn't work; the text doesn't fade at all.

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried rendering it out in different formats, including Quicktime, MPEG & H.264, but the Quicktime format is the only one I've actually been able to view afterwards.

I'm using Bender 2.77 and I've created the text animations in the 3D View as scenes, which I've then added to the VSE. I've also inserted keyframes to adjust the opacity at the end of each animation.

[image]

Comment: Try adding more info to your question. Not sure exactly how you are rendering this or what rendering engine you are using, but video file formats generally do not support alpha channels and as such do not support transparency. Have you tried rendering to a PNG sequence instead?

Comment: If possible at all attached the animated text so that we can take a look at it. It's probably a simple step you have missed. Use this link to upload the blend file http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The most useful thing would be a screen-shot of the section of the VSE where the animation isn't working. I have a pretty good idea what's wrong, but I'd like to confirm...

Comment: I think, @DuarteFarrajotaRamos is on the right track with the alpha problem. Try to just place a solid black Color Strip underneath to confirm this... As I think I read somewhere that only Quicktime is allowing for transparent backgrounds in a video and the fading using opacity is probably resulting in problems in other formats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't change opacity of scene strip in Video Sequence Editor](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6622/cant-change-opacity-of-scene-strip-in-video-sequence-editor)

Comment: thanks very much for all the responses :) i am rushing from one meeting to another at the moment so i will respond in more detail in a few hours, but briefly:
- i'm using the blender render engine; saving to quicktime format, with the RGBA channel selected. i will send files later. thanks!!

Comment: @Samoth - i did have this problem at first also, but used the information on the link you've posted to do the workaround for the bug, and it worked - but only when i'm looking at the .blend file in blender. when i render it out to .mov, the fade isn't there.

Comment: @hawkenfox here is the file: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1295" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1295/) - please understand that this is my first attempt at using blender, so i'm sure i've done all kinds of terrible things ... 
in my latest render, the beginning animations (where the text slides in from the right) did not work. this had worked in previous renders, & i'm not sure what i might have changed that would have affected that. i tried rendering to different formats to see if i could find one where the opacity worked, but i didn't.

Comment: @Matt do you want a screenshot, or can you look at the file i just uploaded? :)

Comment: A screenshot would be very helpful. I usually can't download Blender files when I have access to StackExchange.

Comment: @Matt http://creative-catalyst.com/images/blender_screenshot_130516.png

Comment: i saved it out to pngs & the animations & opacity all works. if i do it this way, would it be best to then import the pngs to a video editor (i only have imovie) & add the audio there, or is there a way that would work to do it in blender? (or would that be silly/more difficult?).

Comment: I highly recommend rendering ANY animation out to images (png or jpg, if you don't need alpha) and then putting them together in the VSE. It's not silly at all. If you're rendering to a video and the render fails part way through, you lose the WHOLE thing. If you're rendering to images and it fails part way through, you at least have all the images you already rendered, and can just start from the last one you have.

Comment: You can import them into Blender with the VSE and even add audio there. Blender is a bit more cumbersome, and not as well documented as others, but it will definitely work. It's what they've used to edit all the Blender open movies ;-)

Comment: It's really strange that it worked rendered to images, but not to a video....

Comment: hi @Matt - i just tried your suggestion, importing the PNG sequence into the VSE, adding the audio & rendering it to Quicktime. this rendered much faster than before (when i was rendering the animation directly to video) BUT in the resulting .mov file, the fades are not there. they are there in the PNGs, they are there when i play it in blender, but they are not there in the rendered file :(

Comment: I KNOW WHAT IT ISSSSSS!!! I'll type it up in an answer....

Comment: @helen, yes compiling rendered frames into a video is MUCH faster than rendering them for the first time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your fades are not working is two-fold.

Firstly, the Quicktime format does not support an alpha channel (I don't know of a video format that does... maybe GIF?).

Secondly, your RGBA colors are not pre-multiplied, but are "straight alpha." A bit of [explanation here](http://www.cgdirector.com/quick-tip-straight-alpha-vs-premultiplied-alpha/).

Consequently, when your frame gets put into the video format, the alpha portion of that image is simply discarded, leaving you with grey text that's no longer transparent. This didn't happen when you rendered it to images because PNG *does* support an alpha channel. Thus, you had text that was still fully grey, but it was *also transparent*. I'll bet that if you rendered to JPGs, you'd lose the fading as well because JPG doesn't support alpha. The question would be whether Blender would pre-multiply your alpha or just discard the alpha channel. I suspect it'd do the same thing that it did with the video and just discard it.

**There are two solutions.** One is to render pre-multiplied alpha. It's not going to be easy to figure out how to do this because it changed recently in the VSE. And there are a couple of different places in the rendering pipeline that pre-multiplication might happen. If anyone else knows, feel free to edit my answer. But this is a poor solution because the background of your video is incidental, not deliberately chosen. It's only fading to black because all the pixels that aren't rendered HAPPEN to be black when the alpha is discarded. This is a reasonable assumption to make, but it's an assumption not a decision.

**The most correct solution** is to make the decision of what to fade TO. You really ought not think in terms of "fade out." Rather, you should always think "fade to..." Even in your video, you're not wanting to "fade out." You're wanting to "fade to *black*." There are a number of ways to accomplish this, depending on what's what's best for your project. The option I'd recommend is to add an Effect Strip -> Color to the bottom layer, and set the color to black. Thus, when your text becomes transparent, there's still something behind it to render.

You could, of course, set the color of the Effect Strip to whatever color you want, and it'd work just as well.

I hope that helps!

Comment: thank you very much, Matt! i'm happy to know there is a reason & i will try to remake it using the second, most correct, solution that you give, adding an effect strip. i will let you know how it goes :)

Comment: it worked! :) i put a black strip under the text, & also when i was checking all the render settings i saw that i could choose PNG instead of JPG for the video codec, so i selected this. then rendered it to quicktime again & now the fades are happening. thanks so much for your help with this :)

Comment: sorry, didn't realise i had to do that! (you're my first answer :) )